# How to select nodes where all children is satisfied?

Tags: postgresql, select, relational-theory, tree

I have a tree structure of light bulbs. I want to turn on all the light bulbs starting from the leafs of the tree. A light bulb cannot be turned on unless all its *immediate* children are turned on.

The relation between the nodes in the tree structure is represented by table A:

**Table A**:

> node_id integer
>   child_node_id integer

Table B represents the nodes in the tree:

**Table B**:

> id integer
>   state boolean

The *state* of table B represents the states true = on and false = off.

**Question**:
I would like to select all the light bulbs which are turned off AND has all *immediate* children turned on.

This is probably very simple, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: Select nodes with all *immediate* children turned on or all children recursively?

Comment: Ahh... yes thats a detail which is missing - thanks!

Comment: Including or excluding nodes without children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first rethink the design. You only need *one* table:

```
CREATE TABLE c (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY
 ,parent_id integer REFERENCES c(id)
 ,state boolean
);
```

With the layout as presented in the question, the query could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.node_id = b.id
LEFT   JOIN a ca ON ca.child_node_id = a.node_id
LEFT   JOIN b cb ON cb.id = ca.node_id AND cb.state = FALSE
WHERE  b.state = FALSE
AND    cb.id IS NULL
```

This *includes* nodes that are turned off and have no children at all.
To *exclude* nodes without children, replace the first `LEFT JOIN` with a plain `JOIN`.

Or, may be faster:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.node_id = b.id
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM   a ca
   JOIN   b cb ON cb.id = ca.node_id
   WHERE  ca.child_node_id = a.node_id
   AND    cb.state = FALSE
   )
```

Comment: My example is simplified and I need the structure for other reasons.